# Visual select current search result

Tags: search, highlight

I have `hlsearch` set, but it sometimes lulls me into thinking t
hat I have the search term visually selected, and can just hit `c` to change it.

The term searched for may not be an easy number of letters, words, even lines - and anyway, I don't want to count.

Is there a way to `vh` (or `ch`), say, where `h` runs until the current highlighting stops?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `gn` motion for that, it selects the next searched element.

You can use it like so:

```
/foo<CR>
gn            -> select the next "foo"
sbar<Esc>     -> (optional) substitute it with "bar"
```

Bonus: To have `.` repeat the search and the change, use a `c` to do everything in one command:

```
/foo<CR>
cgnbar<Esc>
...           -> find and change the 3 next foo
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks. (Anyone that like me misses why `.` will repeat the entire action, and can't make it work - read more carefully - `c` first! Couldn't ask for better.)

Comment: Note that you can also use `gN` to visually select the previous match.

Comment: What's the difference between this and just pressing `n` to get to the next search result?

Comment: it does the change also, so instead of repeating `n.` (next occurence, repeat the modification), you can just press `.` (repeat the modification, which is "change the next occurence")

Comment: Indeed, when `.` invokes `gn`, the original `foo` has disappeared, so Vim searches for the next `foo`. So `gn` does what `n` would have done anyway (and more). But, as with `n`, note that this only works well when `bar` does not contain `foo`!

Comment: I think this is the first time I have seen a motion select a remote chunk of text to replace: previously all `c` commands I used operated either from the current cursor position, or around it.

Comment: This basically sets up an interactive "find-replace dialogue" in raw Vim commands. Type `/[to-find]<Enter>cgn[to-replace]<Esc>`, then just hit `n`/`N` to go forward/back, and `.` to replace. It's a little shorter to type than `:%s/[to-find]/[to-replace]/gc` which is one way to set up a search/replace with confirmation; and that does not start from the current position, nor highlight as you type. But notably, whenever you like, you can choose to set-up other operations (to be done using `.`) with the result (access with `n` or `gn`) instead of replacement (`cgn[to-replace]<Esc>`).